# What Meta informations should I use?

Tags: html, seo, metadata

I see a lot of different point of views on internet concerning [meta tags](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_meta.asp). I've been using them for a while, but I'm now wondering if I've been doing it using the current best practices.

I know that the description is the most important one...

```
<meta name="description" content="This is not a website" />
```

**But what about other meta tag?** Should I even use something else than the description tag? For instance, some say that using keyword is bad practice now because some website overused them and it could lead to lead the website in the spam folder of the search engine.

Lastly, **what is the best practice when writing a description meta tag ?** Using my personal example, right now I have a website referencing various songs. Should I do :

```
<meta name="description" content="MyWebsite - Here, there are songs" />
```

or more something like this on each different page :

```
<meta name="description" content="Song Title X, Artist Y" />
```

or :

```
<meta name="description" content="MyWebsite - Here, there are songs | Song Title X, Artist Y" />
```

or any combination of the previous one... or something else?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of metatags supported by Google's crawler:

[Meta tags - Webmasters/Site owners Help](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812)

Answer (score 0):

Each page should have its own meta description, the description is used to display data about the page once its on the search results screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I received a negative vote on my comment, but let me elaborate, in hopes that the vote will be reversed.

The meta tag **keywords** is an important tags for search engines.  In the case of a music site you might want to add something like the following.  Then as search engines are exploring your site, they will know what words you specifically want your site to be associated with.

Here's an example: 
<meta name="keywords" content="Rock, Jazz, Bluegrass, Blues, Bass, Guitar, 60s, 70s" />

Comment: What did I say that was wrong?  So I don't repeat the same mistake in the future?

Comment: Wasn't me, but I believe meta keywords have a very small impact, or are ignored for the most part now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53081

Comment: I reversed my vote. I voted down because in my question I ask if the keyword meta tag is good practice and you just answered by giving an example of keyword tag.

Comment: And yes I do believe that it is not useful, like s_hewitt said. Could you elaborate if you think that keywords are useful?

Comment: why don't you consider generating them dynamically from javascript or (if you use asp.net) from server side?

Comment: @dada I could, but do I want to? PS: I am using Ruby on Rails for this one.

Comment: In the past, I have registered an URL with dmoz.org which is the feeder for many search engines including Google.
I have also had websites that I didn't register with dmoz.org but just used the keywords or combinations of keywords.  I have found that the combination of keywords plus the site content change the search results.  

ie. Several Boy Scout troops with the same # had websites.  The ones that were toward the top had more relevant description and keywords.

Comment: BTW: I apologize for not seeing the other questions, I see now that you asked three two were bold which I somehow overlooked.  I didn't see the keywords tag, so I was commenting on that one.

Comment: When was that? Because apparently google changed their algorithm at some point. Also don't worry about missing the question, maybe I wasnt clear enough ^^

Comment: It was a couple of years ago.  I guess the 'keywords' meta tag has been really abused.  Apparently it doesn't carry as much weight as it once did.  Although there are some search engines that still use it for various applications.

Answer (score 0):

I do not thik all of your description meta tags. 
Let me elaborate on.

First one, It is good to read(as you know those descriptions will be presented searching), yet it is not so precise! Not good to your SEO.

Second one, Good to SEO, not to readers.

Third one, better than the first two, yet you need polish them.

P.S you can add more words to it.