# How many keywords are ideal for the META keywords tag?

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags

The answers to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53081/html-meta-keyword-description-element-useful-or-not) pointed out that the keywords meta tag in HTML is used by some search engines, such as Yahoo! and Ask.

Now, I know not many of us have direct knowledge of the algorithms behind different search engines, but in your experience, does the number and order of keywords have any effect? Is it better to have fewer or more keywords, and are the keywords that are listed first given higher priority?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no official limit on the number of meta keywords you can have.

Each search engine sets their own rules. However, it is a good practice to have less than 10% of the total words of a page. If for example your page has 300 words it is better to have maximum 30 words in your meta keyword tag. Otherwise could be considered overstuffing.

The only real use is to remind you of the keywords and keyphrases you have optimized for on that page.

Have also in mind that if you place a large number of keywords just for some search engines to see, you could end up ranking less in the others.

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule, you should aim for the following character limits within each of your meta tags:

- Page title – 70 characters
- Meta description – 160 characters
- Meta keywords – No more than 10 keyword phrases

Answer (score 1):

It's essential that you include the watchwords you need your site to be found under in your KEYWORD tag. In the event that a web index creepy crawly finds the same words on your site and in your meta labels, these words will be positioned higher in the inquiry file. Try not to include an excess of words, the most web crawlers will just file the initial 20 words. Verify that you put the 10 most critical catchphrases first.

Attempt to give every page of your site an important title, depiction and catchphrases that compare with the content on your site. A guest will locate the definite data inside of your site, on the right page.

Web search tools like Google show meta labels in their list items. You perform a pursuit filling so as to undertake out:

Rundown thing certain catchphrases. The outcomes you will get is

the title tag and

Rundown thing the little [content](http://www.realpregnancysigns.com/) thing, the portrayal tag.

Answer (score -1):

Stuffing the keywords in the meta tag does not mean guaranteed results.

It's very important that you add the keywords you want your site to be found under in your KEYWORD tag. If a search engine spider finds the same words on your website and in your meta tags, these words will be ranked higher in the search index. Don't add too many words, the most search engines will only index the first 20 words. Make sure that you put the 10 most important keywords first.

Try to give each page of your website a relevant title, description and keywords that correspond with the text on your website. A visitor will find the exact information within your website, on the correct page.

Search engines like Google show meta tags in their search results. You perform a search task by filling out:

1. List item certain keywords.  The results you will get is
2. the title tag and
3. List item the small text item, the description tag.